# Reading/Summing Numbers from a Text File Using Java

Tags: java, sum

I feel like I've made a really simple mistake, but I can't figure out what it is.  I know the program is reading the correct file, but every time I run the program it simply returns 0.0000 as the sum. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: What does the input file look like ?

Comment: As a side note [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) Constructor, that is your's is reading from the String `filename`. I tested this,

```
// Why void? Just return the sum
public double readFile(String filename) {     
  Scanner input = null;
  double sum = 0;
  try {
    input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
      sum += input.nextDouble();
    }
    // output results
    System.out.printf("The total sum of the "
        + "doubles in the input file is %f\n", sum);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    input.close();
  }
```

I got the output

```
The total sum of the doubles in the input file is -3.651000
```

Answer (score 1):

When constructing a Scanner object that will read from a file, you must create a File object and pass it to the Scanner class constructor, it has the following definition:

```
public Scanner(File source)
        throws FileNotFoundException
```

You aren't actually creating a Scanner object on the file, you are creating a Scanner object that is reading the filename as its input, which of course cannot be interpreted as a double.

Change this line:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(filename);
```

To this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( new File(filename) );
```